Switching from asy command to using latexmk gives error
I run Asymptote with Tex-Live under Windows, and have been using the asy command to compile figures. The figures are inlined in the LaTeX document and I use AWK to extract them. And then I learnt about latexmk, which would do a similar job and be much more clever than my AWK script by avoiding unnecessary recompilation. But I consistently get a compilation error. Here is the simplest example I could devise.
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Here it is, or should be:

\begin{asy}
    label("Hello world!");
\end{asy}

\end{document}

The file is named 'minimac.tex'. The error message is:
Package asymptote Warning: file 'minimac-1.tex' not found on input line 12.
Line 12 is \end{asy}.
Any suggestion as to what I am doing wrong, or am missing, would be appreciated.

latexmk will not by default know to re-run asy. The asymptote manual links to a latexmk configuration file to set that up
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/HEAD/doc/latexmkrc
which is
sub asy {return system("asy -o '$_[0]' '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
push @generated_exts, "pre", "%R-[0-9]*.pdf", "%R-[0-9]*.prc", "%R-[0-9]*.tex", "%R-[0-9]*.out", "%R-[0-9]*.pbsdat", "%R.pbsdat", "%R-[0-9]*.eps", "%R-*.asy";

save this as latexmkrc alongside your document.

Thank you David. I think we are moving towards a solution, but have not quite arrived there yet. Two points.

Thank you David. I think we are moving towards a solution, but have not quite arrived there yet. Two points. The first is that earlier posts had pointed to file latexmkrc as pertinent and I had checked that it exists, in exactly the form you pointed me to, in directory \texlive\2024\texmf-dist\tex\latex\asymptote. I had rather hoped it would be found there rather than having to include it in each project. The more pertinent point is that even with the file in the local directory I now get the error shipout failed. Should I be including an explicit shipout?

@BrianShearing I don't use latexmk except for occasional tests like this but I don't think you can make this latexmkrc general as it's specifically adding asy  dependencies so wouldn't be right in general, although it would be possible to have a latexmkrc or even get latexmk changed to pick up asy by default just when needed  (I would guess). I can't help with your error, your example file plus the supplied latexmkrc worked without error for me

I've verified that with the exact .tex file given in the question, and with the latexmkrc code in the answer (with the correction), there are no errors when running latexmk, and the pdf file appears to be correct.

@BrianShearing You can also put the code from this answer in a latexmkrc file in your home directory.  That would save you from having to do that separately for each project.

@JohnCollins yes I was wary of suggesting that as I hadn't looked in detail what this config is doing, in particular if it will mess up documents not using asy and expecting teh default behaviour. If it's safe enough to use as a default for all projects I'll add to the answer, thanks.

From latexmk's own point of view, it's not realistic to have internal support for asy and the many other analogous possibilities.  The reasons are: (1) There is an enormous number of possibilities, and they could easily mutually interfere. (2) The software involved often has many possibilities (e.g., see the list of command line options of asy), so an elementary configuration may need adaption to a user's specific needs.  (3) With annoying regularity, one year's configuration gets broken by the next year's update of the software invoked.

@JohnCollins thanks yes that's what I thought. I think I'll leave the suggestion just to have per-document config that can be tuned to whatever the assymptote requirements are for that document without affecting every latex document processed by that user.

@DavidCarlisle I agree.  Putting the configuration in a project-specific latexmkrc is the best thing to recommend here.  When a user finds that the same configuration is used for multiple projects, then it may make sense to put the configuration in a per-user latexmkrc (in user's home directory).  The configuration can always be overridden per project --- see the section of the latexmk documentation on custom dependencies.

@DavidCarlisle One other advantage of a per-project configuration: If the project directory is shared with other users, e.g., on Dropbox, then there is no need to rely on the other users having the configuration in their home-directory latexmkc.
